# SVN: cannot find committed files

Tags: svn

Relatively new with SVN. I am using svn on local system (OpenSuSE 11.3). I have already created a repo folder with svn. Access repository with file:///path . I am having problems with files bring copied from repo and commit to repo

In my workplace folder I **cannot** see the files from repo after running the checkout command

```
svn checkout file:///home/svn/projects/
```

In my workplace after creating a test file called "testing" and adding it to the svn via

```
svn add testing
```

I can see the .svn folder being created in the same directory. However after committing the file

```
svn commit testing
```

I am taken to vi with

```
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--

A   testing
```

after copying the A testing to before the line and exiting vi with :wq I get

```
Sending        testing
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 1.
```

However back in the repo (/home/svn/projects) I cannot locate the file. My svn is also handling another repo directory but that one is empty and the file doesn't go there either.

Thanks

Comment: What is the output from an "svn info ." and an "svn info testing" in the same location you ran the svn commit from?

Comment: svn info . give

URL: file:///home/svn/projects
Repository Root: file:///home/svn/projects
Repository UUID: 13754e96-d9cd-11df-bd1c-63117db00148
Revision: 0
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Rev: 0
Last Changed Date: 2010-10-17 20:01:06 +1100 (Sun, 17 Oct 2010)

Comment: and svn info testing give
Path: testing
Name: testing
URL: file:///home/svn/projects/testing
Repository Root: file:///home/svn/projects
Repository UUID: 13754e96-d9cd-11df-bd1c-63117db00148
Revision: 3
Node Kind: file
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: kamran
Last Changed Rev: 3
Last Changed Date: 2010-10-18 15:51:45 +1100 (Mon, 18 Oct 2010)
Text Last Updated: 2010-10-18 15:49:52 +1100 (Mon, 18 Oct 2010)
Checksum: 6451fb9e8dce95dddd10c2c270ce01d8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Subversion repository is a database that does not store your files in an obvious way.  In particular it doesn't store the history for a file in a file with the same name.

The only place you will see your file with the name attached is in a checked out working directory, never in the repository itself.

Also, the `A testing` line you see in the commit message file is there as a helpful hint informing you what will be committed.  You do not need to move it in order to commit your file, and leaving it in place or deleting it will not result in your file not being committed.  There is a reason the line reading `--This line, and those below, will be ignored--` is there.

As a side note, I cannot recommend Subversion as the version control system to use for any new projects.  If you have a specific reason to use it, do so.  But if you don't, I would very strongly recommend checking out [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [git](http://git-scm.com/) and using one of those two instead.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a ways to import other project files your svn repo is handling to your work directory?

Comment: @Jaswal K: That would be the `svn update` or the `svn co` command.